# Fetching nested Collections in HSQLDB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I have a Person table in my database. One person can have many persons below itself and many persons upper itself (self join):

```
@Entity 
public class Person {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    @JoinTable(name = "person",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent_person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "child_person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private SortedSet<Person> childPersons;

    ...
}
```

I have PersonRepository and when I fetch personRepository.findPersonById(1) using development environment (mysql) then I see all hierarchy, for example:

```
person1
    person2
        person4
        person5
    person3
```

but when I'm using this method in test environment (hsqldb) then afer fetching personRepository.findPersonById(1) I see only this:

```
person1
    person2
    person3
```

What do I need to change to make my test environment work like a development environment when it comes to fetching data (not only 1 level down)?

**I noticed that** in dev environment (mysql) my nested collections are of type PersistentSortedSet in all levels, but in test env (hsqldb) I see that person on the top has **PersistentSortedSet** with children (person2, person3) but when I look down to person2 I see that te same field with children is of type **TreeSet** and size = 0

Comment: If you want to go relational (SQL) then separate your ManyToMany to a couple of OneToMany, the first one for parents, the second for childrens. But this looks like a graph-based datastore at first glance.

Comment: I cannot change this relation. Only things I can change is configuration of db or my application without changing entities.

Comment: Your strategy suffers from the N+1 performance issue. I would suggest you avoid the primitive CRUD methods and use specialized ones, unless you are retrieving a handful of rows only.

Comment: can you confirm that the test environment database contains the full hierarchy?

Comment: "I would suggest you avoid the primitive CRUD methods and use specialized ones."
@TheImpaler I don't understand. What are primitive CRUD methods and what are specialized?

Comment: @tremendous7 I have a method to get all children 3 levels down (recursive method):
public void getChildren(person, Set<Person> allChildren3LevelsDown, int actualLevel)
Before calling it I get person from db using getPersonById (Spring Data JPA default impl.). While running dev env I see whole hierarchy, but in tests I see only 1 level hierarchy like in my first post (I don't see person2 children).
I modified getChildren() method to fetch person in the beginning, but It calls DB on every level - probably this is not good so I'm wondering how to change it to be the same like in dev env.